# Quickstart.py failed to run due to selenium issue

Tags: python, selenium

I cannot find anywhere solution to my issue.

I have installed Instapy successfully in Amazon lightsail Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Linux. Thank you so much for any suggestion.

When I tried to run the simple test script below.

I get as part of the error -> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

```
This is the script I am trying to run. Full Error is further below. 

# imports
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run


# login credentials -  password delete intentionally. 
insta_username = '******'
insta_password = '*****'

# get an InstaPy session!
# set headless_browser=True to run InstaPy in the background
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
password=insta_password,
headless_browser=True)


with smart_run(session):

 # activity            
session.like_by_tags(["natgeo"], amount=10)
```

I get the following error...

I can identify 2 potential errors

1. File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
2. selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

I think the errors has to be related to selenium and Firefox browser , as the error is prompted while trying to run the browser in the background (headless_browser=True)

See full error message below

```
 ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._. 
Workspace in use: "/home/ubuntu/InstaPy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 25, in <module>
    headless_browser=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/instapy/instapy.py", line 318, in __init__
    self.logger,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/instapy/browser.py", line 114, in set_selenium_local_session
    options=firefox_options,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today, then realized the second File call was referencing Firefox. So, I loaded Firefox on the server and things worked perfectly. Not sure how the "Quickstart" missed this...

Found out how to do that here:
https://vitux.com/4-ways-to-install-mozilla-firefox-in-ubuntu/

> Method 2: From the Official Ubuntu Repository-through the Command Line

```
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt install firefox
```